# How to set incremental CSS classes in each Table Cell with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, classname

I have a table populated via a DB and it renders like so (it could have any number of columns referring to "time", 5 columns, 8 columns, 2 columns, etc):

```
<table id="eventInfo">
<tr> 
     <td class="name">John</td> 
     <td class="date">Dec 20</td> 
     <td class="**time**">2pm</td>
     <td class="**time**">3pm</td>
     <td class="**time**">4pm</td>
     <td class="event">Birthday</td>                
 </tr>
 <tr> 
     <td class="name">Billy</td> 
     <td class="date">Dec 19</td> 
     <td class="**time**">6pm</td>
     <td class="**time**">7pm</td>
     <td class="**time**">8pm</td>
     <td class="event">Birthday</td>         
</tr>
```

With jQuery, I'd like to go through each Table Row and incrementally set an additional class-name on only the Table Cells where "class='time'" so that the result would be:

```
<table id="eventInfo">
<tr> 
     <td class="name">John</td> 
     <td class="date">Dec 20</td> 
     <td class="**time** **timenum-1**">2pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-2**">3pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-3**">4pm</td>
     <td class="event">Birthday</td>                
 </tr>
 <tr> 
     <td class="name">Billy</td> 
     <td class="date">Dec 19</td> 
     <td class="**time** **timenum-1**">6pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-2**">7pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-3**">8pm</td>
     <td class="event">Birthday</td>         
</tr>
```

I've only been able to get it to count all of the Table Cells where "class='time'" and not each set within its own Table Row. This is what I've tried with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("table#eventInfo tr").each(function() {   
            var tcount = 0;
            $("td.time").attr("class", function() {
              return "timenum-" + tcount++;
            })
            //writes out the results in each TD
            .each(function() {
              $("span", this).html("(class = '<b>" + this.className + "</b>')");
            });    

        });

    });
```

Unfortunately, this only results in:

```
<table id="eventInfo">
<tr> 
     <td class="name">John</td> 
     <td class="date">Dec 20</td> 
     <td class="**time** **timenum-1**">2pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-2**">3pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-3**">4pm</td>
     <td class="event">Birthday</td>                
 </tr>
 <tr> 
     <td class="name">Billy</td> 
     <td class="date">Dec 19</td> 
     <td class="**time** **timenum-4**">6pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-5**">7pm</td>
     <td class="**time** **timenum-6**">8pm</td>
     <td class="event">Birthday</td>         
</tr>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the `span` for? And why mess with `.html` when you could use `.addClass()`? http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Hi dnagirl, thanks for asking... the following was being used only so I could quickly see what was happening in the browser window and not part of the actual problem. 

    //writes out the results in each TD
            .each(function() {
              $("span", this).html("(class = '<b>" + this.className + "</b>')");
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("td.time")` select **all** table cells with class `time` not only those in that row. Add a reference to the row as the (second) context parameter just as you are doing in the other `each` loop: `$("td.time", this)`

Comment: Hi RoToRa, thank you! I'm still working with the code, but wanted to let you know this has apparently solved my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("table#eventInfo tr").each(function() {
         $(this).children('td').addClass(function (index) {
             return 'timenum-' + (index + 1);
         }); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I like the use of 'index' - thank you for the help!